# Resize a picturebox by mouse

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I'm developing a WPF app and I'm trying to resize a picturebox by mouse like that 
http://i54.tinypic.com/vkf0z.jpg 
how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that, one of it would be to use adorners like described in [this post](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/).